# Typeahead example using http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, typeahead.js

I'm trying to create a working example of bs3-typeahead when the data is gathered from an $http.get call, but I can't. I can get it to work when I assign the source from outside the http.get method, but no from the inside.

I have no idea what am I missing here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here's my code, it has the non-http version working. [plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/LzNoD3GHEhOSnrP0hcHU/) or copy it from below.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>    
<head>
  <!-- GOOD ORDER -->
  <!--    JQUERY      -->
  <script data-require="jquery@1.10.1" data-semver="1.10.1" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
  <!--    TPEAHEAD    -->
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead/master/bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
  <!--    ANGULARJS   -->
  <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
  <!--    UI-BOOTSTRAP-TPLS   -->
  <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.0.3.js"></script>
  <!--    ANGULAR-BOOTSTRAP-TYPEAHEAD     -->
  <script src="https://rawgithub.com/davidkonrad/angular-bootstrap3-typeahead/master/angular-bootstrap3-typeahead.js"></script>
  <!--    BOOTSTRAP   -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-app="bootstrap3-typeahead-example">
    <div ng-controller="sampleCtrl">
      <div>
        <h2>bootstrap3-typeahead example</h2>
        <h4>selected value: {{ value }}</h4> States:
        <input type="text" bs3-typeahead bs3-source="source" ng-model="value" />
        <br /> States (from http.get):
        <input type="text" bs3-typeahead bs3-source="source_http" ng-model="http_value" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script>
    (function(angular) {
      'use strict';
      angular.module('bootstrap3-typeahead-example', ['ui.bootstrap', 'bootstrap3-typeahead']).
      controller('sampleCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {

        $scope.HttpTest = function() {
          $http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
            .then(
              function(data) {
                $scope.source_http = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
                  'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
                  'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
                  'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
                  'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
                  'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
                  'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
                  'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
                  'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
                ];
              },
              function(error) {
                console.log(error);
              });
        };

        $scope.source = ['Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California',
          'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware', 'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii',
          'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky', 'Louisiana',
          'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota',
          'Mississippi', 'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire',
          'New Jersey', 'New Mexico', 'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota',
          'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania', 'Rhode Island',
          'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
          'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
        ];

        $scope.value = undefined;
        $scope.http_value = undefined;
        $scope.HttpTest();
      }]);
    })(angular);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `bs3-promise` instead of `bs3-source`.

```
<input type="text" bs3-typeahead bs3-promise="source_http" ng-model="http_value" />
```

From [documentation](https://github.com/davidkonrad/angular-bootstrap3-typeahead):

> bs3-promise does not actually use promises. If you specify bs3-promise then the directive will simply wait and $watch the referred $scope variable. Once the variable is set the typeahead is initialised. This also mean, that if you later on change the variable you are referring to in bs3-promise, then the typeahead will be reinitailised with the new variable as source. bs3-promise let you easily change source on the fly.